# How to get lat long from database using c#.net

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, leaflet

1. My ajax call looks like this .

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "map.aspx/getCityPopulation2",
    //data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var points = L.geoJson(data, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: ratIcon })
                    marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.Source + '<br/>');
                    return marker;
                }
            }).addTo(pointsCluster);

            mymap.addLayer(pointsCluster);
        }
        });
```

2. Here is my code behind from where query is executing.

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<cityPopulation2> getCityPopulation2()
{
    List<cityPopulation2> p = new List<cityPopulation2>();

    using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=Localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=post;"))
    {
        string myQuery = "select complaintlgeolon,complaintlgeolat from mandapet.pgr_demo_view";
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cityPopulation2 cpData = new cityPopulation2();
                cpData.lat = Convert.ToInt32(dr["complaintlgeolon"]);
                cpData.lng = Convert.ToInt32(dr["complaintlgeolon"]);

                p.Add(cpData);
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

}

```
 public class cityPopulation2
    {
        public int lat { get; set; }
        public int lng { get; set; }
       // public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

3.Please any one guide me where i'm going wrong. i need to fetch data as j son and plot Markers

Comment: what is `pData1` here ?

Comment: its just a string

Comment: And what is `jsonData` in the ajax call ?

Comment: What error, if any, are you getting, and which line?

Comment: Here `data` define more that one time in ajax call

Comment: this is the error im getting  http://localhost:53399/map.aspx/getCityPopulation2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: *its just a string* I don't think so. look at your code it's `List<string>`

Comment: Thanks for all your replies can any one help me out to fetch latlong from database and convert it to json and plot markers

Comment: Why is the ajax call type POST ??? it should  be get as you are only getting a value

Comment: Its working perfect with  code  var pointsCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
    $.getJSON("rodents.json", function (data) {
        var ratIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'maps/future.png',
            iconSize: [30, 30]
        });
        var points = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: ratIcon })
                marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.Source + '<br/>');
                return marker;
            }
        }).addTo(pointsCluster);
    });
    mymap.addLayer(pointsCluster);

Comment: @imtiyaz, Please read first how to call method from ajax, then you'll automatically get an answer of your question

Comment: yeah @Div but can u suggest me how to convert database data to json while fetching with query ..thnks in advance

Comment: @too_cool i have changed it to GET but din't work

Comment: @imtiyaz,*yeah,but can u suggest me how to convert database data to json while fetching with query...* So, basically what is your question? How to convert data into json or  *How to get lat long from database using c#.net?*

Comment: @Div Thanks for your support. Actually I have latlong in my database so i want to get the latlong from database and with that latlong have to plot markers.. for this do i need to convert my data to json or not? any example will be highly appreciated

Comment: @imtiyaz, Let's check together, Is your method call from your ajax call?

Comment: What is value of `lat/long` in Database ? Looks like it is `float` and you are trying to convert it to `int`

Comment: @Div Yeah im trying to call method from ajax call in which my query is stored

Comment: @Leopard Yeah its in float type

Comment: @imtiyaz, It called or not?

Comment: @Div its showing This error  (http://localhost:53399/map.aspx/getCityPopulation2?{} Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: @imtiyaz yes, it means first issue: your method not called from ajax.

Comment: @Div  yeah thats the problem

Comment: @imtiyaz than why are you assigining it to `int` change type of `cityPopulation2` properties to `float`

Comment: @imtiyaz Read [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx), once your method call from your ajax, will move to the issue.

Comment: Yeah i have done @ Leopard but no output

Comment: @Leopard is that really issue right now? it may be but it seems like OP stuck on method not call from ajax.

Comment: If you want manipulate gis data with postgres, you need to use postgis and it'll give you structure to manipulate them (point, shape...) and geoJson et javascript tools will work with them.

Comment: @DIV yeah i have read that thanks but my ajax call also of same type then why i'm getting error

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque thanks fro ur reply can you please explain with more specific

Comment: @imtiyaz  Can you just put break point and make sure your method is getting called

Comment: @too_cool Yeah im getting error which i have posted above while calling ajax call

Comment: See my comment bellow I am asking you to put a break point on Visual Studio and Debug the code

Comment: @too_cool if method not getting called then how VS gives an error?

Comment: @Div how you can be so sure the method is not getting called...you can all so get the same error when there is a run time exception on code..as he don't have `try catch`

Comment: @too_cool I have done break point stil the same error

Comment: @imtiyaz  What happen did the break point got hit..?? One more thing Do you know how to debug a code...

Comment: @imtiyaz http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17103/net-entity-framework-with-postgis postgis is a plugin of postgres to manipulate GIS data

Comment: @too_cool, I think i should ask this question before*One more thing Do you know how to debug a code..*, because I've tried copy and paste same code at my side and break point got hit

Comment: @too_cool i have kept break point but the controler is not moving to that method

Comment: @imtiyaz are you not clear about what you're doing.. *controller* are sure ?

Comment: *but the controler is not moving to that method* Can anyone clarify this ??

Comment: It's too confusing now!!!

Comment: Flag it to close.

Comment: @Div i mean to say break poin is not detecting in this

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments if you what to return json..You can use `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ASerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

  //you can create your own custom converter of cityPopulation2
  ASerializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] {new cityPopulation2()});
var Json = ASerializer.Serialize(p);
return Json;
```

Also make sure your DB values for `lag and long` are `int`

Comment: My latlong are in double precision

Comment: Simple put a break point on your method and If its getting called just Debug through your code and see what error its showing..In VS